# Implementing finding alghoritm with for loops and fmincon function

Tags: matlab, for-loop, optimization

I am trying to implement this alghoritm for finding a new constraint:[image]

In my case we take only `3` natural numbers i.e `1,2, 3`. 
The sets associated with those natural numbers are `M1`, `M2` and `M3`. Instead of the Newton Method in `II(2)`, I chose a solver provided by Matlab `fmincon`.
Here is my code that is not working!

```
function[s_new]= checking2(M1,M2,M3,x)
M1=linspace(0,1,10)';
M2=linspace(0,1,100)';
M3=linspace(0,1,1000)'; 
bool1=0;
eta = 10^-8;
pocz=[];
max=-100;
x = [0.1,0.1]'; % warunek początkowy
A = [];
b = [];
Aeq = [];
beq = [];
Set=[0,1];
g = @(x,s) 5*x(1).^2.*sin(pi.*sqrt(s))./(1+s.^2) - x(2);
g_new = @(s) -g(x,s);

for i=1:length(M1)
    if g(x,M1(i,:))>eta
       s_new=M1(i,:);
       bool1=1;
    end
end
if ~bool1
    for i=1:length(M1)
        if g(x,M1(i,:))>max
           pocz=M1(i,:);
           max=g(x,M1(i,:));
        end
    end
    if max<-eta
        bool1=1;
    end
end
if ~bool1
    s_maybe = fmincon(g_new,pocz,A,b,Aeq,beq,min(Set),max(Set));
    if g(x,s_maybe)>eta
       s_new=s_maybe;
       bool1=1;
    end
end
if ~bool1
    for i=1:length(M2)
        if g(x,M2(i,:))>eta
           s_new=M2(i,:);
           bool1=1;
        end
     end
end
if ~bool1
    for i=1:length(M2)
        if g(x,M2(i,:))>max
           pocz=M2(i,:);
           max=g(x,M2(i,:));
        end
    end
    if max<-eta
    bool1=1;
    end
end
if ~bool1        
    s_maybe = fmincon(g_new,pocz,A,b,Aeq,beq,min(Set),max(Set));
    if g(x,s_maybe)>eta
       s_new=s_maybe;
       bool1=1;
    end
end
if ~bool1
    for i=1:length(M3)
        if g(x,M3(i,:))>eta
           s_new=M3(i,:);
           bool1=1;
        end
    end
end
if ~bool1
    s_new = 1;
end
disp(s_new);
```

The problem is:

```
Undefined function or variable 's_new'.

Error in checking2 (line 70)
disp(s_new);
```

So basically everything might be wrong, but I suppose it is something with fmincon.

EDIT:

The purpose of the alghoritm is to find a minimum of an objective function f(x), satisfying all the constraints g(x,s)<=0 for all s in S, where S is an infinite set (some interval in our case).

What my alghoritm does, at first it takes some finite subset of S and calculates the minimum of f on this set, then I am trying to update S with some s_new. This alghoritm that I am trying to implement is exactly the procedure for creating s_new. Then if it works properly, I will add s_new to my subset and calculate the minimum on the new set, and so on until g(x,s)<=eta, where eta is a small number.

Comment: I would suggest to simply initalize `s_new` with any value you consider, as it seems that none of the conditions is met to create it.

Comment: Besides I suggest to use [`return`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/return.html) instead of the boolean variable.

Comment: I think something must be wrong with the code, its impossible that the criteria are not met for a couple of different x points.

Comment: `fmincon` optimizes over `s` only, change `g_new` to  `g_new = @(s) -g(x,s)`

Comment: @Adam Thank you for your comment it is obviousely right, could you tell me one more thing? Supposingly none of the conditions is meet, why does it state that s_new is not defined even though i added this last line to attribuite 1 to s_new in that case?

Comment: I rewrite the algorithm for you,  `max` is the maximum value of `g` not a predefined random number

Answer (score 1):

I rewrite the algorithm, read through the comments

```
clc
clear

lb = 0;
ub = 1;

% Given 
l = 3;
M1=linspace(lb,ub,10)';
M2=linspace(lb,ub,100)';
M3=linspace(lb,ub,1000)'; 

% one boolean value for each Matrix
bool = zeros(1,3);

eta = 10^-8;
% Used as  fmincon  initial starting guess
pocz = nan;

% Used to store the new finding s that fits all the conditions
s_new = nan;

% Fixed x
x = [0.1,0]';

% fmincon linear constraints 
A = [];
b = [];
Aeq = [];
beq = [];

% Main function 
g = @(x,s) 5*x(1).^2*sin(pi*sqrt(s))/(1+s.^2) - x(2);

% Optimization concerns s only, don't include x as x is fixed 
g_new = @(s) -g(x,s);

% Assuming the maximum is reached at the upper bound, used in(II)(2)
max_s = ub;
maxfun = g(x, max_s);

% Use a cell, for each iteration use a specific matrix M
M = {M1, M2, M3};

for j = 1: length(M)
    % used in (II)(1)
    check = 0;
    step = 1;
    % (I) step 1
    for i = 1:length(M{j})

        % Stopping criteria

        if g(x, M{j}(i)) > eta
            s_new = M{j}(i);
            bool(j) = 1;
            break;
        else


          % Function maximum value for next step (II)
            if maxfun < g(x, M{j}(i))
                maxfun = g(x, M{j}(i));

                % To be used in fmincon as pocz
                max_s = M{j}(i);
            end


        end 
    % To be used in (II)(1)
        if maxfun < -eta
              check = 1;
        end
    end
    % End of (I)

    % Put (II)(1) here  step 2

     if ~bool(j) && check
            step = step + 1;
            % Stopping criteria 
            if step >= l
                disp('S_new not defined');
                break;
            end

            % otherwise go to the next M

      end

    % (II)(2) step 3
    if ~bool(j)
        step = step + 1;
        if maxfun >= -eta && maxfun <= eta 
            pocz = max_s;        
            bool(j) = 1;
        end

    end

    %% EDIT: if bool(j) changed to if ~bool(j)
    %  (II)(2) Continue
    if ~bool(j)
        s_maybe = fmincon(g_new,pocz,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub);

        % End of (II)(2)


        % (II)(2)-1 step 4
        step = step + 1;  
        if g(x, s_maybe) > eta

            s_new = s_maybe;

            bool(j) = 1;
        end
        % End of (II)(2)-1
    end

        % Put (II)(2) here  step 5
        if ~bool(j)
            step = step + 1; 
            % Stopping criteria 
            if step >= l
                disp('S_new not defined');
                break;
            end

            % otherwise go to the next M

        end


end
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, as always quite helpful, however for instance for x = [0.1,0]', it produces an error: Objective function is undefined at initial point. Fmincon cannot continue. which is quite weird.

Comment: Could you explain clearly the purpose of this algorithm ? Like the `x` and `s`meanings

Comment: Take a look at the edit, if it is not clear, you can either ask for more or read here as the alghoritm I am trying to implement comes from this article: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220133528_A_New_Exchange_Method_for_Convex_Semi-Infinite_Programming.

Comment: I just updated the answer, run again. The change I made can be found at `EDIT` section just right before `fmincon`